# Как вывести список постов на странице настроек плагина?

Tags: wordpress

Пишу плагин, в нем для служебных целей используется свой тип постов.
Блок редактирования этих постов скрыт в админке.
Я хочу вывести список постов на странице настроек плагина, в обычном стандартном виде, но нигде не нашел какой-либо информации об этом.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это сделать.

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_table

Comment: О, то, что нужно, спасибо! Оформишь ответом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В WP есть базовый класс для создания произвольных списков. Именно на нём построена выдача постов в админке с пагинацией. Называется класс WP_List_Table, информация на русском находится [тут](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_table).